# How to get bootstrap navbar sliding transitions working?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, transition

Just getting started with Bootstrap and want to have the navbar dropdowns have a nice slide transition but am not sure if this is possible within the default bootstrap options.

My simplified html is:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-close-others="true" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Home</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
   </ul>
```

I have jquery and the bootstrap.min.js files included but the dropdown only works on a click  and without a nice slide transition...Ideally i want it to work something like this: http://themeforest.net/item/clava-multipurpose-responsive-html-template/full_screen_preview/6480105

Do i have to add hover effects and if so how? With javascript or css transitions?
Or is this something already built in to Bootstrap?

Thanks for any help

G

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS transitions on the `.dropdown` and `.open > .dropdown` like this..

### Demo: http://bootply.com/104214

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);  
  opacity:1;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  opacity:.3;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  display: block; 
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```